# In React (Native), where should I store screen height information?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native top App component, I wrote some logic to track screen height. It works quite well:

```
    const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState({
        max:     {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height},
        min:     {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height},
        current: {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height},
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener("change", ({ window }) => {
            setWindowDimensions((previousWindowDimensions) =>
                {return {
                    max:     {width: Math.max(previousWindowDimensions.width, window.width), height: Math.max(previousWindowDimensions.height, window.height)},
                    min:     {width: Math.min(previousWindowDimensions.width, window.width), height: Math.min(previousWindowDimensions.height, window.height)},
                    current: {width: window.width, height: window.height},
            }});
            }
        );
        return () => subscription?.remove();
    });
```

This `windowDimensions` variable is useful for some lower components, since I want them to be aware of changes caused by virtual keyboards, URL bars hiding or showing up, etc. Currently, I'm using `useContext` to make it available to the whole component tree, but I've read that it's best to keep as much out of App-wide contexts as possible. I have a gut feeling that this could somehow be re-written as a custom hook, or maybe there's a better way to make this data available just as needed. Is there a cleaner way to have this logic in a single place, but be shared easily down the component tree just as needed? Just to be clear, it works now. I'm looking for best practice. Installing react-redux, or another library, is certainly an option, but not the knowledge I'm looking for in this case.

Here's the rest of what I'm currently doing, just so it's clear:

```
/* Imports */
export const GameContext = createContext();

const App: () => Node = () => {
/* That code from the start, plus more game logic */
    return (
            <GameContext.Provider value={{players: players, game: game, windowDimensions: windowDimensions}}>
            /* Components */
            </GameContext.Provider>

    );
};
```

Comment: This is a good candidate for a custom hook

Comment: Check this example https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/

Answer (score 0):

Hey cdehaan you can make a custom hook like this

```js
const useDimensionUtils = () => {
const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState({
        max:     {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height},
        min:     {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height},
        current: {width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: Dimensions.get('window').height},
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener("change", ({ window }) => {
            setWindowDimensions((previousWindowDimensions) =>
                {return {
                    max:     {width: Math.max(previousWindowDimensions.width, window.width), height: Math.max(previousWindowDimensions.height, window.height)},
                    min:     {width: Math.min(previousWindowDimensions.width, window.width), height: Math.min(previousWindowDimensions.height, window.height)},
                    current: {width: window.width, height: window.height},
            }});
            }
        );
        return () => subscription?.remove();
    });

return windowDimensions;

}
```

And whenever you wanna use it just do ,

`const dimensions = useDimensionUtils()` in your file :)

Hope it helps ,feel free for doubts